# Convert count on a pivot to a bit / flag?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have a working pivot query:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        select [cid], [cid] as c, [Category] from [MyTbl] where [Conditional] = 0
    )
as src PIVOT(COUNT(c) FOR [Category] in ([SciFi],[Horror],[Comedy])) AS piv
```

Which is great, it'll produce something like this:

```
cid | SciFi | Horror | Comedy
-----------------------------
 1      0        3       0
 2      1        2       1
 3      6        2       4
```

But actually I don't want the count, I just want a true or false flag (just 0 or 1 would be best)

```
cid | SciFi | Horror | Comedy
-----------------------------
 1      0        1       0
 2      1        1       1
 3      0        1       1
```

I tried wrapping the `count(c)` bit in a case statement but I'm just getting syntax errors - assuming pivots don't work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend conditional aggregation. It is much more flexible that vendor-specific `pivot` syntax, and lets you do what you want easily:

```
select cid,
    max(case when category = 'SciFi'  then 1 else 0 end) SciFi,
    max(case when category = 'Horror' then 1 else 0 end) Horror,
    max(case when category = 'Comedy' then 1 else 0 end) Comedy
from mytbl
where conditional = 0
group by cid
```